# How to fix org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException:Entry not found by path Exception while doing commit using Egit

Tags: java, git, rcp, egit, jgit

I am trying to integrate Git in my existing RCP application,
For that i have imported egit.core and egit.io plugin as source project into my application and when i tried to commit the file using egit's commit() from CommitOperation Class i am getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Entry not found by path: D:\Test\file.txt
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.createTemporaryIndex(CommitCommand.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:194)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.commit(CommitOperation.java:255)
... 39 more
```

And when i debugged through the code to find out where the  exception is happening, it is on CommitCommand.class at the following point

```
// there must be no unprocessed paths left at this point; otherwise an
    // untracked or unknown path has been specified
    for (int i = 0; i < onlyProcessed.length; i++)
        if (!onlyProcessed[i])
            throw new JGitInternalException(MessageFormat.format(
                    JGitText.get().entryNotFoundByPath, only.get(i)));
```

I have no idea what the unprocessed path here is meant by? 
I am able to access the path. can anyone help me how to proceed further

Comment: The path to the file is an absolute path, JGuts CommitCommand expects paths to be relative to the working directory root of the repository.

Comment: I have tried by specifying relative path but still i am getting the exception org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Entry not found by path: ../Test/file.txt

Comment: The base path is the path of the repo, so if c:/test ist the path to your working directory, then the path would be just file.txt